# Javascript slice.call(arguments) and recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, arguments

I have a simple recursive javascript function that can be called with additional arguments:

```
AllDataRows(grid.Rows, process);
AllDataRows(grid.Rows, process, storeIDs);
```

The problem is that if the function has to call itself then any additional arguments are lost. I tried using `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2)` to pass the arguments along, but they end up as one element arrays. The cb function then fails because it isn't expecting an array (it would be a hidden textbox).

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

```
function AllDataRows(rowList, cb) {
  if (rowList.getRow(0).GroupByRow) {
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; rowList.length; i++)
      AllDataRows(rowList.getRow(i).Rows, cb);
  } else {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    for (var j = 0; j &lt; rowList.length; j++)
      cb.apply(rowList.getRow(j), args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function AllDataRows(rowList, cb) {
  if (rowList.getRow(0).GroupByRow) {
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; rowList.length; i++) {
      var aa = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
      aa[0] = rowList.getRow(1).Rows;
      AllDataRows.apply(this, aa);
    }
  } else {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    for (var j = 0; j &lt; rowList.length; j++)
      cb.apply(rowList.getRow(j), args);
  }
}
```

Just use `apply` when you make the recursive call, fixing up the argument array to account for the sub-group you're opening up.

Comment: Doh! Nice and simple. Thanks.